# Problem with GHUnit + Hudson/Jenkins in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4, hudson, jenkins, gh-unit

I've followed this very good [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ycxFcIPhQg&feature=related) on how to configure GHUnit in Xcode 4 and integrate it with Hudson/Jenkins.

Everything seems to work fine when all test cases pass, but when a test case fails, the Hudson/Jenkins doesn't create the "test results" where you can actually check details about the test cases that failed.

Checking the console output I see this:

```
Test Suite 'Tests' finished.
Executed 2 of 2 tests, with 1 failures in 0.024 seconds (0 disabled).

Failed tests:
    ExampleTest/testFoo

Wrote JUnit XML successfully.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" build/FirstUnitTestingProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Script-DA6E61A913A94E9F00DE8C5B.sh
(1 failure)
make: *** [test] Error 65
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

The script that is being executed can be found [here](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/blob/master/Scripts/RunTests.sh).

It fails in both, Jenkins and Hudson with the same exception.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Vic, by looking at console report everything seems normal. This is how console output will be when a test case fails. I tried the scenario by changing the test case to fail. I was able to get full details of failed test. I am using Hudson. Take a look at the below image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If a test fails then the `RunTests.sh` exits with a non zero status and Xcode considers that the build failed. I encountered the same issue and I found this workaround: replace the last line of `RunTests.sh` by this one:

```
#exit $RETVAL
exit 0
```

Therefore the builds keep on running even if some tests fails.

Moreover if you are using a post-build action to publish the tests results the build is marked as *unstable* when some tests fails (which is exactly the behaviour I wanted).